# Resize image(s) in CleanShot X

Tags: macos, image-editing

For all the [CleanShot X](https://cleanshot.com/features) fans, do you know if they can also resize an image?

[image: Screenshot of CleanShot X]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not at the moment. It’s one of the features I most wish it had as I almost always have to resize a screenshot after capture.

I rely on [Retrobatch](https://flyingmeat.com/retrobatch/), which is excellent for fast resizing of one or more images. Highly recommended.